# What's causing "validity error : ID <some-id> already defined"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, nokogiri, libxml2

These just started showing up in my tests and I'm not sure where it's coming from:

```
element section: validity error : ID with-header already defined
element section: validity error : ID with-header already defined
element section: validity error : ID with-header already defined
```

`with-header` is the ID

These errors (warnings?!? because tests pass) would appear to be erroneous as I can look at the page and there is only one `#with-header` so not sure what's throwing them and why?

My preliminary research uncovers [this Nokogiri issue](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1208) ([and another](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1196)) pointing the finger at **libxml2** but the issue(s) appear closed so why are these only now appearing for me?

Any ideas how to fix or at least suppress the warnings so they don't vomit all over my tests?

Using:

- **RSpec** (3.3.2)
- **Nokogiri** (1.6.6.2)
- **libxml2**: stable 2.9.2 (bottled), HEAD

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed, but not yet released. It will be released in the 1.6.7 version.

Source:

- https://github.com/rubys/nokogumbo/issues/21
- https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1262

It does work, but the output is annoying :)

Comment: Looks like this might have been fixed back in March but `1.6.7` still not released?!?  If you're familiar with the library do you know a stable branch with the patch that I can grab until these guys get around to v1.6.7 official?

Comment: Indeed. I am guessing releasing nokogiri is not so easy, to include all the binaries/dependencies, and building for different platforms as well. So afaik you cannot just install the gem from github (which you could easily do with a pure ruby gem).